# Triggering Automation Test Scripts of Remote Machine from ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, triggers, scripting, remote-access

In our project, we need to meet one Requirement.
"Triggering automation test scripts which are located remotely from asp.net web page"

We are developing a DashBoard for our Testing Team. They want to trigger their test scripts from the webpage.

I have been googling since 3 days, to find the approaches to meet the requirement. And to know whether its possible or not.
Please kindly share your ideas.

Comment: I tired a lot to find the approaches, to meet the requirement. After that only I am posting my query here. So kindly don't think that without trying anything, I posted here

Comment: I find WMI, through which we can access remote machines somewhat. is this approach provide ways to meet my requirement..??

Comment: You need to provide more information, especially:
(1) What version of ASP.NET?
(2) What automation test scripts are these? Are they part of a continuous integration environment? Are they part of the ASP.NET web code base or do they exist somewhere else? This will change answers significantly.

Comment: we are using .net framework 4.5. And automation scripts are vbscripts.
the senario is
I need to trigger the scripts from a webpage in a remote machine

Remote IP : 172.1.128.105
Scripts directory: C:\TestScripts\controlPanel.vbs

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide access to the scripts for your webserver in order to hit them.

The first step is to provide remote access to your visual basic scripts. I would do this by writing a small application to provide a RESTful endpoint that your webserver can then hit. Another option is a shell script on your web server that SSH connects to the remote machine and runs the scripts provided. You could then call the the shell script with your ASP.NET application.

You need to start by thinking about how to expose your VB scripts to the internet. Once you have that answer, running them from your webserver is easier.